# Issue in Accessing Angular app through Spring app

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I was trying to make my front end of a spring mvc application using angular. I am assuming that anything in webapps folder is accessible through browser. This way I added angular part in a folder to webapps in my last project and it worked fine. This time when I created a folder under webapps and built my angular app there. But I can't get access to it in browser. My spring application is working fine.

My spring configuration file contains:

```
    <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also,

```
     <bean id="urlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>


            <entry key="/dpc/*.d">
                <ref bean="dac2Controller" />
            </entry>

            <entry key="/products/*.f">
                <ref bean="productController" />
            </entry>



        </map>

    </property>
</bean>
```

The code in controller is :

```
@RequestMapping("/products/p.f")
public String list(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.getAllProducts());
return "products";
}
```

when I use the URL:

```
  http://localhost:8080/dpc2-kk-web-search/products/p.f
```

It works fine.

But when I add angular code under webapps (folder dpc2), and in script.jsp:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider


.when('/searchProducts', {
    templateUrl : 'ProductsSearch.jsp',
    controller : 'SearchController'
})
```

When I tried to access through URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/dpc2-kk-web-search/dpc2/#/searchProducts
```

I am not getting the corresponding page. What configurations needs to put in web.xml to get access to folders and files in webapps through browser.

Comment: what do you get in the console ??

Comment: I am getting Failed to GET Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) script.js, angular.js, angular-route.js, controller.js and so on..

Comment: that means your files are not added properly the application check there